# How can I upload multiple files using PHP without a counter?

Tags: php, html, loops, server

I currently have a website setup where photos that are uploaded are moved from temporary storage on the server side. This works fine but some of my clients have hundreds of photos to upload and slow connections. My server times out after 5mins, meaning it doesn't finish and the files are not moved to permanent storage.

Is there a way to allow the user to pick multiple photos and they upload one by one so that my server doesn't time out? Or is there a better way to amend this code to allow the clients to upload more photos without timing out?

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    // Count total files
    $countfiles = count($_FILES['file']['name']);

    // Looping all files
    for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];

    // Upload file
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],'upload/'.$filename);
    echo "$filename <br>";
        }
    echo "$countfiles file(s) successfully uploaded";
        } 
    ?>
```

Comment: You can use the php function `set_time_limit ( int $seconds )` to allow the script to execute longer. If you use it in the for-loop, you can give each iteration a specific time limit. http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: If you need to upload hundreds of photos through slow connections, maybe HTTP isn't the way to go.

Comment: Search GitHub there are LOTS of plugins with Javascript that do exactly this.

Comment: I'll give that a go. Not sure the server will allow one continuous upload though @Jeppsen

Comment: @Loek I'm working to a spec I can't change though I'm afraid

Comment: @Martin I am having a hard time finding anything that just uses vanilla JS.. Another requirement I am unfortunately stuck with. Know of anything good?

Comment: @WhatsThat Fair enough, you could try the other solutions first :) In my experience though, if a spec is bad, you should let the deciding people know that. They can decide whether to change the spec or not, but at least you've informed them that the task is harder than expected and will probably take longer because of that.

Comment: @WhatsThat -- try this: [blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/basic-plus.html)

Comment: @WhatsThat had such a problem once. came up with a solution that uploads multiple files in chunks. so i take 1mb of first file upload it, the server responses if chunk is written -> take 2nd chunk... if all chunk of one file is on server, the server merges chunks back to a whole file. That way the server wont stop execution

Comment: @Nitro.de Any chance we could have a look? Github link?

Comment: @WhatsThat no sorry, but i could give you an explanation in chat if you want

Comment: @WhatsThat sitting here half the day waiting https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174776/js-php-chunkupload

Comment: @Nitro.de Thanks, I found a solution though. Much appreciated!